# Click a button then run onchange function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to perform the `onclick` function and then only perform the `onchange` function to get the file and upload the file.

Here is the code:
Click the button and perform `handleFileSelect()`.

```
<input type="button" name="next" onclick="handleFileSelect();" value="Next" />
```

Here is the `handleFileSelect()` function:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload',
      type: 'post',
      data: f,
      processData: false,
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer <MY_ACCESS_TOKEN>",
        "Dropbox-API-Arg": '{"path": "/' + f.name + '","mode": "add"}'
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(f);
        //        document.getElementById("uploadApp").submit();
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  }
}
document.getElementById('my-file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

In the above function, there is a `onchange` from the `input='file'` element to get the file.

Actually I just want to click the `input='file'` element, get the file, and then click the `"Next"` button and then only upload my file. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Did you try....?

Comment: remove the eventlistener -))

Comment: Yes, you can first onClick event you get files and store into the variable. After next button click take that variable and process with FileReader API. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload for more info related about handle file.